Processing files that manipulate database sequentially?
How do I process a range of files (fs.readdir or fs.readdirSync) one by one in sequence that manipulate a database with data that the next file depends on?
So, for each iteration I actually need to read data just inserted from the previous operation.
I've fiddled with stuff like this, but get all sorts of errors; 'error: deadlock detected' or errors related to the previous data not being updated before the next operation runs.
const Processes = require('processes');

function readFiles () {
    fs.readdir( 'path/to/folder', ( err, files ) => {
        if ( err )return;

        if ( files.length ) {
            files.forEach( file => {
                let fileData = '';
                let fileStream = fs.createReadStream( 'path/to/folder/' + file );

                if ( ! fileStream ) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    fileStream.on('data', chunk => {
                        fileData += chunk;
                    });
        
                    fileStream.on('end', async () => {
                        await Processes.processFileWithDatabaseOperations( 'path/to/folder/' + file );
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

// processes.js
export function processFileWithDatabaseOperations ( file ) {
    return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
        fs.readFile( file, 'latin1', ( err, data ) => {
            if ( err )return;
            // Here insert data into the database based on the previous operation
        });
    });
}



I have work of these type of function but you have to specify file type you want to add to the database.

SOLUTION:
const Processes = require('processes');

function readFiles () {
    fs.readdir('path/to/folder', async ( err, files ) => {
        if ( err ) return;
    
        if ( files.length ) {
            for ( let i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) { // array.forEach does not support async / await
                await processFileWithDatabaseOperations( 'path/to/folder' + files[ i ] )
                .then(( result ) => {
                    console.log(`${result}`);
                });
            };
        }
    });
}   

// processes.js
export function processFileWithDatabaseOperations ( file ) {
    return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
        fs.readFile( file, 'latin1', ( err, data ) => {
            if ( err )return;

            resolve( "Whenever all operations to the db has been done" );
        });
    });
}

